# Access to my files on Android

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, dropbox

I am thinking of subscribing to Dropbox which is slightly more costly than Ubuntu one but I need access to my files on the go, and I prefer to use my smartphone to my netbook most of the time **as I like to travel light.**

**I do not want to stream music**, I want access to my files only.

Whereas there is a **free** app for Dropbox to access said files, there isn't one for Ubuntu.

I would be prepared to wait a while if you have got this in hand, have you actually given this any thought?

***Please tell me whether I should ignore Ubuntu One and link up with Dropbox?***

Answer (score 8):

There is now an **[Ubuntu One Files](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubuntuone.android.files)** app for Android available.

([Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/update-arrives-for-ubuntu-one-android-app/))

Answer (score 3):

There will be a client available sooner than 11.10, just be patient for a very little while  :)

Comment: That Android files application is now available in Google Play (the Android Market); there are two apps there, one for files and one for music streaming.

Answer (score 0):

This is a highly subjective question, but I'll try to answer with my experiences.

I'm on the same boat. I have been a Dropbox subscriber for two years, and I want badly to change to Ubuntu One mainly because I want to support Canonical.

After some tests, yesterday (May 26th, 2011), I subscribed Dropbox for another year. The performance is way way better (at least for my files, mainly pictures and code). And I badly need the Android support (now not next year), like you I started to travel only with my phone and I don't want to carry my laptop again (I changed my netbook for a 12" laptop last year).

I'm going to stay with Dropbox another year and check again Ubuntu One next year. If it fits my needs I'll change in a breeze.

Note that this is just my experience, maybe other people with different files (like maybe music), or who uses a lot some of the extra syncing features from Ubuntu One (like contacts, bookmarks or favorites) will find Ubuntu One better for them.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question:

FOR NOW

Use the free version of Dropbox for now and use their android app, keeping in mind that the android app does NOT do an automatic sync, it syncs your Dropbox listings, you must choose what you want downloaded to your phone. Also you must choose from android what you wish to "share" back to the cloud, but you can do that with anyfile anywhere on your phone or card. IMO this is a seamless experience.

Of course everything is availabe from the Dropbox website anyway.

LATER

If and when Ubuntu One comes on board Android you can try it a switch if you wish.