# Sync ubuntu and phone

Tags: sync, android

Can you sync ubuntu and android phone, without having to install ubuntu on phone, even if I have to how much space will it take?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "sync", possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/45308/access-to-my-files-on-android

Comment: However, 'sync' usually means address book, messages, calendar ..

Comment: Where do you want to sync your data? Mozilla Thunderbird? Evolution? Somewhere else?